# Photos copied via bluetooth from LG 4X HD to Xperia Z are no longer sorted

Tags: bluetooth, photos

I recently copied all my photos and videos from my LG to my Xperia Z using Bluetooth. It took a while but the all copied over fine and are in  a single album, *My Album*, under a folder named *Bluetooth*.

The problem is that they are now unsorted. On the LG phone, I had all of the media files organized by different albums but now they are all in a single album.

Is there a way to copy these using Bluetooth or another method without losing the album structure and naming?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have lost your folder structure ("albums") due to the Bluetooth transfer. A possible solution would be to copy not over Bluetooth but rather with a Computer (USB) or over Wifi and a network share, to retain the folder structure.

There are many file managers available in the play store which can use network shares. You may also consider using DropBox or that kind of service.

Answer (score 0):

If both the devices have NFC then try that or else as @Markus has said you can only do is transfer only through the USB cable. USB cable is a better option for faster data transfer and the best part it retains the file structure in the way it was stored on another device.

For that first you need to store the file as it is on the System later connect your xperia and transfer the same file .

USB transfer is best for moving files >10MB (more then 5-6 photos) to reduce time whereas NFC is best for single or couple of photos